# Understanding Postgres Query

Tags: postgresql

Regarding the difference between...

```
select * from table_a where id != 30 and name != 'Kevin';
```

and

```
select * from table_a where id != 30 or name != 'Kevin';
```

First one means, `"select all rows from table_a where the id is not 30 and the name is not Kevin"`.

So {Id, Name} row of {30, 'Bill'} would be returned from this first query.

But, the second one means, `"select all rows from table_a where the id is not 30 or the name is not 'Kevin'"`.

So the above {30, 'Bill'} would **not** be returned from this second query.

Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table_a where id != 30 and name != 'Kevin';
```

> So {Id, Name} row of {30, 'Bill'} would be returned from this first
>   query.

No, it wouldn't.

```
select * from table_a where id != 30 or name != 'Kevin';
```

> So the above {30, 'Bill'} would **not** be returned from this second
>   query.

No, it would. You have the logic backwards. Just try it.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The second query means "select all rows where the id is not 30 or the name is not 'Kevin'", hence a name of 'Bill' qualifies the record for inclusion in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Recap:

```
A   B   not(A)  not(B)      AND     OR
1   1   0         0         0       0
1   0   0         1         0       1
0   1   1         0         0       1
0   0   1         1         1       1
```

So, the two query's will return the same rows only if:

1- id=30 and name='Kevin'

or

2- id!=30 and name!='Kevin'

Answer (score 0):

Quick logic expression transformation tip:

NOT (A AND B) == NOT A OR NOT B

NOT (A OR B) == NOT A AND NOT B

Comment: You should relate this to the question being asked. Why does DeMorgan's apply here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws